Insert ignore into database coping old record and changing 1 field in new record
$sql = {"INSERT IGNORE INTO  membership  WHERE Member_id= 'A4C1905' (`Name`,`GivenName`,`SpouceName`,`SpouceGiven`,`Address`,`City`,`Prov`,`PostalCode`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Secondary Email`,`Region`,`Year`,`visible`,`Mailing_Info`,`Member_ID`,`LastUpdateDate`,`Payment_Date`,`Payment_Type`,`Payment_Amount`,`Payment_Comment`,`Payment_Year`,`Nonrenreason`)   VALUES ('Ruck','John', 'Joan', 'Clint', '2045 Lakeshore Blvd. W. Suite # 3803 ', 'Toronto ', 'ON', 'L0P 1K0', '905-877-9812', 'tow.t@hotmail.com', '', 'GPR', '2025', 'N', 'Mr. Clint Adcock','' , '2024-10-14', '2024-10-14', 'Cheque', '50', 'no comment', '2025','ill' )";

get the following message which is being caused by where statement.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Member_id= 'A4C1905' (Name,GivenName,SpouceName,SpouceGiven,`Addre' at line 1

remove the where statement and it works.  Problem need where statement to get the record I need to copy vales from.  I know the values can be '' if I get the where to work.

INSERT is for adding new rows. Use UPDATE to modify an existing row.

If you want to copy an old row into a new row, use INSERT INTO tablename (columnnames) SELECT ... FROM tablename WHERE ...

Not trying to modify old record trying to create new record which has all the data from the original except a few of the fields has been modified.  EG. Old rick 1905 KLR Y  use where to find this record then create new record rick 1905 GPR N.

Then do what I said above.

$sql = {"INSERT INTO  membership (,Region,Primary,) FROM membership WHERE  MEMBER_ID = 'A$C1905' VALUES 'GPR','N');    Is this kind of what you are saying..... please remember i'm a newbe

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-insert-into-select/

Always add a dbms tag when asking SQL questions.

You have to use a SELECT query to get the values from the old row.
INSERT IGNORE INTO membership
(`Name`,`GivenName`,`SpouceName`,`SpouceGiven`,`Address`,`City`,`Prov`,`PostalCode`,`Phone`,
 `Email`,`Secondary Email`,`Region`,`Year`,`visible`,`Mailing_Info`,`Member_ID`,`LastUpdateDate`,
 `Payment_Date`,`Payment_Type`,`Payment_Amount`,`Payment_Comment`,`Payment_Year`,`Nonrenreason`,
 columns_to_keep)
SELECT 'Ruck','John', 'Joan', 'Clint', '2045 Lakeshore Blvd. W. Suite # 3803 ', 'Toronto ', 
    'ON', 'L0P 1K0', '905-877-9812', 'tow.t@hotmail.com', '', 'GPR', '2025', 'N', 'Mr. Clint Adcock',
    '' , '2024-10-14', '2024-10-14', 'Cheque', '50', 'no comment', '2025','ill',
    columns_to_keep
FROM membership
WHERE member_id = 'A4C1905'

Replace both columns_to_keep with all the columns you're copying from the old row to the new row.
